# Most performant way to update DOM in TVJS app?

Tags: dom, tvos, tvml, tvjs

Updating the DOM in TVJS seems almost instantaneous in one instance (~1000 lockup items in DOM) and in another blocks the UI for 30 seconds (~10000 lockup items).

The document reference is stored as a reference and updated with a few attributes:

```
var element = doc.getElementsByTagName('lockup').item(index);
element.setAttribute('id', 'item-highlight');
element.setAttribute('autoHighlight', 'true');
```

Is there a more performant/efficient way of updating the DOM?

Answer (score 0):

Am I right that you have a loop around the shown block (see `index`)?
I would guess, `doc.getElementsByTagName('lockup')` - each time crunching through the whole DOM - takes up a considerable amount of time. As it will return the same array every time, pull it in front of the loop. Something like this...

```
var elems = doc.getElementsByTagName('lockup')
for (var elem of elems) {
  elem.setAttribute(...)
}
```

Comment: The index is a bit misleading, it's simply a parameter that is passed in dynamically to determine which lockup item to set the attribute on. The actual lockup (pun intended) happens at the time the element in the dom is updated.